# Showing that if T has an infinite model, it has models at least models of every cardinality.

Tags: logic, model-theory

The question follows: "Prove the following, by using a compactness argument: If T has an infinite model, then for every cardinal k, T has a model of cardinality at least k."

I don't get what the compactness argument part wants, and I feel like using upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem is enough, since it gives us elementary extensions of this model (M) for every cardinality larger than the max of the cardinalities of the model M and the vocabulary.

Is my reasoning incorrect? Can I not use Löwenheim-Skolem here?

Comment: The question is designed precisely to get you thinking about how you would *prove* the upward Löwenheim-Skolem using compactness. Using L-S itself to answer it would go against its spirit.

Comment: I agree with Z.A.K., but I just wanted to confirm that your reasoning is correct, you could use upward LS.

Comment: Ah I see! Trying to prove upwards L-S seems very daunting though.

Comment: @Shotoria It depends on the exact statement how hard that is going to be. The simplest version is essentially the exercise you ask about, and that is very doable. Have you thought about how to do this with just compactness, so without using upward LS?

Comment: The only way I can think of using compactness is when i've already constructed some kind of model to show that it is satisfiable. But I do not know how to construct these other models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M$ be an infinite model of $T$. Let $\kappa$ be any cardinal and let $\{c_i : i < \kappa\}$ be a set of new constant symbols. Define
$$
\Sigma = \{c_i \neq c_j : i < j < \kappa\}.
$$
We will prove that $T \cup \Sigma$ is satisfiable. Let $\Sigma_0 \subseteq \Sigma$ be finite. Then only a finite number of the new constant symbols is mentioned in $\Sigma_0$. By interpreting these as distinct elements in $M$, which we can do because $M$ is infinite, we get that $M \models T \cup \Sigma_0$. So every finite subset of $T \cup \Sigma$ is satisfiable, and so by compactness $T \cup \Sigma$ itself is satisfiable. Let $N$ be a model of $T \cup \Sigma$. Then $N$ is a model of $T$ and because $N \models \Sigma$ it has at least $\kappa$ distinct elements.

Bonus exercise: can you adjust the proof so that $N$ is actually an elementary extension of $M$?

Comment: Doesn't kappa have an upper bound of |M| since the constants need to be distinct elements of M?

Comment: No, that is where the compactness trick comes in: we only need to worry about finitely many constants at a time.

Comment: Why do we prove that T union sigma are consistent instead of proving satisfiability?, I know they are consistent but because of the phrasing it feels like I am missing something.

Comment: Consistent and satisfiable means the same thing, because of soundness and completeness. You're right that satisfiable is maybe better here. I will edit to use that, but really they are equivalent.

Comment: Should we not make it be $T_0 \cup \Sigma_0$ where $T_0$ is a finite subset of $T$? Because T could be infinite?

Comment: Not necessary, if $T \cup \Sigma_0$ is satisfiable then $T_0 \cup \Sigma_0$ is satisfiable for any $T_0 \subseteq T$.

Comment: Ohh, since $M$ already models $T$!